# CC2538 USB CDC Driver issue

Tags: usb, driver, cdc

I'd like to install the Texas Instrument's CDC Driver for the CC2538EM (from the cc2538_foundation_firmware_1_0_1_0). But when I try to install it via the Device Management, I get the message that a proper device driver has been found, yet it couldn't be installed due to an error (Error Code 28).

Does anyone know why TI's Driver doesn't work and how to solve that Problem?

Thanks a lot!

alogheo

Comment: Do the Hardware Ids of the device you plugged in match the IDs listed in the INF file for that driver?  Could you give more details about what you tried, including links to the USB firmware you are running and the hardware you are running it on, links to the driver, the relevant Hardware Ids, a description of how you attempted to install the driver, and a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Vendor and Product ID are both correct.
the firmware: http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2538-sw (including the driver file)

Comment: In the Device Manager I selected the USB device, right click -> Properties -> Driver -> Update Driver and the selected the INF file

Comment: The entire Error message: "Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install it. \n >>[Driver Name]<< \n The drivers for this device are not installed (Code 28)"